# How to properly reuse object pointers to widgets in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Suppose I have some widgets that I want to reuse their pointers, as
they are dynamically allocated and removed.
Example:

```
GtkWidget *widget1;
GtkWidget *widget2;
GtkWidget *widget3;
 
int main()
{
    widget1 = gtk_new_type1_widget();
    widget2 = gtk_new_type2_widget();
    widget3 = gtk_new_type3_widget();

    gtk_init(0, NULL);

    //All other GTK initializing stuff, window
    //creation and widgets loading from file...

    gtk_main();

    return 0;


}
```

Now suppose that I want to reuse `widget1`, `widget2` and `widget3` to point to a new widget. What is the proper to way to "free" the widgets before I allocate a new one? Do I need to call `gtk_widget_destroy` to clean all references? Or I can call something like `g_clear_object`?

Example:

```
gtk_widget_destroy(widget1);
g_clear_object(&widget1);
widget1 = gtk_new_type1_widget();

gtk_widget_destroy(widget2);
g_clear_object(&widget2);
widget2 = gtk_new_type2_widget();

gtk_widget_destroy(widget3);
g_clear_object(&widget3);
widget3 = gtk_new_type3_widget();
```

Also, a second question related to this one. If I create a function that wraps another gtk object creating function and set some properties for the objects, do I need to call `g_object_unref` ? Since the reference count will grow.

Example:

```
GtkWidget *create_widget_with_properties()
{
    GtkWidget *widget;
    widget = gtk_new_type1_widget();
    set_widget_specific_properties(widget);
    g_object_unref(widget);
    return widget;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** I solved my problem. For those who have the same doubts can
look my [post](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-properly-reuse-object-pointers-to-widgets-in-gtk-3/8960/6) at Gnome discourse. Here are some tips:

- Understand reference counting
- Understand floating reference concept in GTK
- Understand memory management in GTK

If you understand the concepts above you will know how to handle widgets object pointers. There are useful links in the post.

Gtk version: `3.24.20`

Comment: How do you know you don't need the widgets any more?  It's common that you don't need to manually maintain *pointers* to most widgets, but it's quite rare that you know before the program terminates that you have no more use for a given widget.  At least in a program large enough that it makes sense to worry about reclaiming memory.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, in my case I will substitute widgets for a new one, so I don't need that widget anymore. Also they are in a specific context, which makes it easier to track their use.

Comment: I am glad you resolved your issue.  Please consider writing a self-answer to the question (that actually answers it, which your edit to the question does not).  This is how an intention to share your knowledge and experience is realized here on SO.